# Форматирование результата Timedelta

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
a = '01.11.2019'
c = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%d.%m.%Y") - timedelta(days = 60)
c = c.strptime("%d.%m.%Y")
print(c)
```

У меня есть скрипт, который делает get запрос. Мне необходимо подставить в строку запроса дату на два месяца ранее той, которую ввел пользователь и она должна быть в формате %d.%m.%Y. Как я уже догадался timedelta не поддерживает метод strptime.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как перевести переменную с к формату %d.%m.%Y

Comment: Вам и не надо форматировать `timedelta`, т.к. `type(datetime - timedelta) == datetime`. Т.е. Вам по-прежнему нужны методы объекта `datetime`.

Comment: все верно. Я использовал неподходящий метод

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужен метод `str`**f**`time()`, а не `str`**p**`time()`. `strptime` преобразует строку в объект `datetime`, `strftime` наоборот, из `datetime` делает строку.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!